# Self-interruption

Tags: meaning

Is there a term for a self-interruption like in the excerpt below?

"From one perspective, it’s actually basic as hell, and it’s embarrassing that it took me till the age of thirty-eight to set it out in this fashion. Still, maybe that’s just how long it has taken me fully to process the crisis in masculinity **— wait, let me own that phrase: the crisis in my masculinity —** and try, from now on, to make significant progress. I hope that some men will find my words useful."

I get that the writer pauses to add emphasis on the statement and also to make the statement more personal in order to create feeling on intemacy in reader, but does it have a specific term? Is it a certain rhetorical device or something?

Answer (score 1):

This is **parenthesis**:

> 3. Grammar. a qualifying, explanatory, or appositive word, phrase, clause, or sentence that interrupts a syntactic construction without otherwise affecting it, having often a characteristic intonation and indicated in writing by commas, parentheses, or dashes, as in William Smith—you must know him—is coming tonight.

--Definition from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/parenthesis?s=t)